# What happened to many of the people in unfortunate places when snapped back?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Like in Far from Home, we see students appearing in the court at random places, presumably the places they were at when they got snapped away, or in Black Widow, Yelena getting snapped and coming back right where she was, with of course, the place around her changing.

What would be happening to those who got snapped in air, in the sea, in the middle of the road or in a building which isn't there 5 years later, or somewhere where a building/a heavy object stands now?

Did/could this happen or not? If yes, how'd they (Avengers, governments etc.) deal with all the mayhem caused after Hulk's snap? Are the Stones good or "intelligent" enough to help Hulk snap all of them back in a safe place?

Comment: Answered very competently on our sister site: [What happened to people in unsafe areas during the Blip?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/215730/20774). In short, they were moved somewhere with immediate safety.

Answer (score 2):

[**This answer** by TheLethalCarrot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215730/what-happened-to-people-in-unsafe-areas-during-the-blip) over on Science Fiction & Fantasy SE covers this.

Quoted for completeness...

> Jon Watts, the director for *Spider-Man: Far From Home* touched on this a bit in a few interviews and whilst he mainly avoids answering the question he does state that they would be Blipped back safely.
>
> > “What would happen to people in motion, if you’re in a car or in an airplane?” said the director. “Obviously, they didn’t blip back in the middle of the sky and fall to the Earth because so many people would die.”
>
> Watts said, “There are so many questions, but we just stuck with the ones that made sense in our story.”
>
> So what would happen to people who came back who were previously in an airplane?
>
> “I was like, you know what, I’m not going to touch that one,” Watts joked, explaining the idea was really that everyone came back in one piece.
>
> “That’s the thing. Everyone arrived back safely somehow. I don’t think suddenly people were raptured back to Earth and plummeted into the ocean. That would not be the happy ending that [Tony Stark] was planning.”
>
> <sub>[HuffPost, 'Spider-Man: Far From Home' Director Sets Record Straight On 'Plot Hole'](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/spider-man-far-from-home-plot-hole_n_5d092bc8e4b06ad4d2572561)</sub>
>
> Kevin Feige, the president of Marvel Studios, had previously answered this question as well during a AMA on reddit. He again states the people would be brought back safely.
>
> > **dwallace3099:** People have expressed views that, in Endgame, those brought back by the snap could have died in accidents (like someone being brought back 100 ft in the air where a plane used to be). Is it possible that Hulk, when doing the snap, not only brought everyone back, but also brought them back in a safe place?
>
> **KevFeige:** We refer to the version of Hulk in Endgame as Smart Hulk. So, yes.
>
> <sub>[reddit, r/marvelstudios, Hi reddit, I'm Kevin Feige. AMAA](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bp084n/hi_reddit_im_kevin_feige_amaa/ennasj9/)</sub>